# Decompose matrix in blocks with det = 0

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, matrix-decomposition, block-matrices

I have a linear system which I know $\left[A\right]$ and $\left[B\right]$ and want to find $\left[X\right]$

$$
\left[A\right]_{(n+m) \times(n+m) } \cdot \left[X\right]_{n+m}  =
\left[B\right]_{n+m } 
$$

Unfortunately, $\det(A) = 0$, which means I cannot solve it.

$m$ of the eigenvalues of $A$ are zero and the other $n$ are non-zero

So, I search a way to transform $A$ and $B$ into

$$
\left[A\right] =
\begin{bmatrix}
\left[0\right]_{m \times m} & \left[0\right]_{m \times n} \\
\left[0\right]_{n \times m} & \left[A_{22}\right]_{n \times n}
\end{bmatrix}; \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \left[B\right] =
\begin{bmatrix}
\left[0\right]_{m}\\
\left[B_{2}\right]_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

And then find $\left[X_{2}\right]_{n}$ such

$$
\left[A_{22}\right] \cdot \left[X_{2}\right] = \left[B_{2}\right]
$$

And mount

$$
\left[X\right] =
\begin{bmatrix}[\underbrace{X_1}_{0}] \\ \left[X_2\right]
\end{bmatrix}
$$

**My question is**: How can I find $\left[A_{22}\right]$ and $\left[B_{2}\right]$ such that $\det(A_{22}) \ne 0$, and keeps the original equation $AX = B$?

**Example 1**:

$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
3 \\
5 
\end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow X = \dfrac{1}{3}\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
7
\end{bmatrix}
$$

**Example 2**:

$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 2 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
10 \\
14 \\
4 
\end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow X = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
8 \\
-2 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

**PS**: I'm searching for an algorithm in python to do it. I thought about computing the eigenvalues, getting those which are not zero, mounting the matrix $A_{22}$ with the non-zero eigenvectors and after that solving the system. But it seems costly to do it.

Comment: I am totally confused by your question. If you know $A$, then how is there any question of finding $A_{22}$? If $\det(A_{22}) = 0$, then you have to know that $B_2$ is in its column space or there will be no solution. What is making $\det A$ be $0$?

Comment: I edited the question. Let me know if there's still any question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is essentially a classic way to solve a rank-deficient linear system $AX = B$ (that is, when $A$ is square but it has a nontrivial null space) by finding a minimum norm, least-squares solution. If your linear system has a genuine solution, then it will be obtained as well.

Mathematically, this can be computed using the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse). This is the linear transformation obtained by sending the range of $A$ to orthogonal complement of its null space (the map between these two subspaces is an isomorphism and represents the inverse of $A_{22}$ that you described in your question), and sending the orthogonal complement of the range to $0$.

Algorithmically, this can be computed by using the QR factorization or the [Singular Value Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition). I'll describe the SVD approach here. By obtaining the factorization $A = U \Sigma V^*$, where $U,V$ are unitary matrices and $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix of singular values, then its pseudoinverse is given by
$$
V \Sigma^{\dagger} U^*, \quad \Sigma^{\dagger} = \mathrm{diag}(\sigma_1^{-1}, \ldots, \sigma_k^{-1}, 0, \ldots, 0),
$$
and where $\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_k$ are the non-zero singular values of $A$.

In Python, such algorithms are implemented as linear least squares solvers. See for example [this implementation in Numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html).